# DB2: Is it possible to connect to DB2 from application suppressing password and using trusted connectivity

Tags: db2

DB2 is our Application DB and we are connecting from our application using the DB2 libraries.

However, we store the credentials in an encrypted format and use that for connecting.

If DB2 has an option to connect using a trusted user (like Informix), we could remove the password stored, though it is encrypted.

Anyone knows, is it possible with DB2?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try the `Client` authentication method or Kerberos Authentication.
[Authentication methods for servers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005435.html).
[Kerberos authentication](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0011990.html).